# Could a quantum computer simulate any system based on different types of logic?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic, quantum-physics, computation, philosophy-of-computer-science

Quantum computing is based on quantum mechanics (obviously) which has different logical rules than classical/Boolean logic.

However, does this mean that a quantum computer could simulate or process systems based on quantum logic and classical logic? Or could it also be used for every other kind of logic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-classical_logic) (apart from classical and quantum logics)?

Comment: See [Quantum computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing): the hardware is based on quantum physics but the "logic" is not quantum logic: "In principle, a non-quantum (classical) computer can solve the same computational problems as a quantum computer, given enough time. Quantum advantage comes in the form of time complexity rather than computability, and quantum complexity theory shows that some quantum algorithms for carefully selected tasks require exponentially fewer computational steps than the best known non-quantum algorithms."

Comment: And see [Quantum Algorithms](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-quantcomp/#QuanAlgo) and [Quantum Information](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-entangle/) and [Quantum gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate).

Comment: Compare with [Quantum logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic#Relationship_to_other_logics).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but couldn't there be computers that deal with systems based on quantum logic (just as our brains do)?

Comment: I agree that doesn't really mean anything to say that a quantum computer is based on quantum logic. I must add something important: do you think that classical computers cannot simulate or process systems based on other logics?